# We need to split the Windows tag

Tags: discussion, tags

The tag wiki for [windows](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows) explains the problem well enough:

> refers to both Microsoft's operating system by that name, and the rectangular frame with a title bar and UI inside it.

We really need unique tags for the [windows-os](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-os) and [windows](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows) as a general concept. What should we name each?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yah. Let's split them into [windows-os](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-os) and [window](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/window).

Comment: Agreed. I'll (slowly) start retagging the windows question. Anyone can feel free to suggest better tag wikis for them.

Comment: My only concern with **window** is that it's still not so clear when presented on it's own that it's about the UI element and could be easily confused with the OS.

Comment: @JonW: We just need to make sure that the tag wiki is clear. It's visible during tagging, after all.

Comment: @JonW windows-os still shows up when you type window so it should be fairly clear

Answer (score 0):

[windows-os](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-os) is fine. Perhaps [windows-wimp](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-wimp) or just [wimp](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wimp) instead?

Comment: I don't think people would understand what wimp is and come up with that as a tag on their own when asking questions.

Comment: I was thinking "window" to make it clear it's not the OS

Comment: @CharlesBoyung provided it has a good wiki article about it then it shouldn't be a problem. But I agree that it's not as well known a term so probably wouldn't be picked by the question posters and would rely on community edits to attach the relevant tag.